# Speak failed: not bound to TTS Engine

Tags: android, text-to-speech, voice-recognition

I am trying to make an application that uses Speech to text, and Text to speech.
So the algorithm of this program is:
1 - when the user runs this program, it will call voice Recognition
2 - after getting the input from the user, the program will repeat the same word the user said.

here's my code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, OnClickListener {

protected static final int REQUEST_OK = 1234;
String userSay;
TextView text1;
private TextToSpeech tts;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
    text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    tts=new TextToSpeech(this, this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
   public void onPause(){
      if(tts !=null){
         tts.stop();
         tts.shutdown();
      }
      super.onPause();
   }

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Success!");        
        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {
            String anyThing = " ";
            speakIt(anyThing);
        }
        return;
    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }

}

private void speakIt(String someThing) {
    Log.e("something: ", someThing);
        tts.speak(someThing, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        Log.e("TTS", "called");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
     //i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
    text1.setText(" ");
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "I'm listen to you...");
     try {
         startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_OK);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Error initializing speech to text engine.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode==REQUEST_OK  && resultCode==-1) {
        ArrayList<String> thingsYouSaid = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

        userSay = thingsYouSaid.get(0);

    }
    try {
        String FinalValue = getDataMethod(hasil);
        text1.setText(FinalValue);
        Log.v("Status OK: ", FinalValue);
        speakIt(FinalValue);
        Log.v("speakIt: ", "called");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private String getDataMethod(String num) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
    num = "You say, " + num;
    return num;
}


   }
```

But the application won't say anything. And in the logcat I got an error that says:
TextToSpeech(10335): speak failed: not bound to TTS

When before I made this application, I made it in separate parts: Text to Speech, and Speech to Text.
Both of that applications ran normally.
I don't know why this error occurs.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

One problem is that you are calling:

```
speakIt(FinalValue);
```

inside:

```
onActivityResult(
```

while in onPause, you execute:

```
if(tts !=null){
    tts.stop();
    tts.shutdown();
}
```

so once, you open your sub activity, onPause is called and tts is shutdown, returning back you use such destroyed tts which is wrong and can cause such behaviour.

You can move your code from onPause to onStop, and your init code to onStart. In onActivityResult set some class instance variable with data to speak inside onInit.

Comment: So, first I move onPause to onStop. and code in onInit to onStart. but I didn't understand on this statment "In onActivityResult set some class instance variable with data to speak inside onInit". may you explain it again?

Comment: Your `onStart` code will initialize TTS back, but you can use it only after `onInit` gets called. onActivityResult will get called before onInit, so you must set some variable in onActivityResult, that will be used in onInit to speak once TTS initializes.

Comment: so I call the speakIt method onInit, with make something like If(FinalValue != null){speakIt(FinalValue)} in onInit?

Comment: assuming that you set FinalValue in onActivityResult, then yes

Comment: but it still won't say anything.

Comment: you should debug it, check if FinalValue contains text that should be spoken, investigate logcat for TTS errors, I remember that at least SVOX engine happens to hangup if you have lots of app crashes - which happens during development (even when you kill your app from eclipse), then the only work around for me was to reboot device.